# Rake test doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

When I type

> rake test

it doesn't do anything.

I have to test all files one by one by typing for example:

> ruby -Itest test/models/post_test.rb

I created application with -T flag so it skipped tests. I recently added them manually though; maybe i forgot to add some file? idk;/

Comment: What is in your `Rakefile`? You may need to define a default task.

Comment: rakefile: http://pastebin.com/fYyMipYd

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem and I found the issue was in my config/application.rb file.

Using -T caused this:

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

I simply changed it to:

```
require "rails/all"
```

and my rake tasks work.  You could also uncomment the commented test require, but requiring all seems easier and ensures I get any new libraries that may get added down the road.